# msgraphv3Client connection from spfx webpart

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

I try to connect to msgraph to read data with msgraphClientV3 from a spfx webpart.

I followed this :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-microsoft-graph-apis

I want to get result from /me/memberOf endpoint.
I added these in my packageSolution File :

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "User.Read"
  },
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "User.ReadBasic.All"
  },
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "Directory.Read.All"
  }
]
```

and call it with  :

```
context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient("3")
  .then((client: MSGraphClientV3): void => {
    client.api('/me/memberOf')
      .get((error, messages: any, rawResponse?: any) => {
        console.log("***********result*********")
        if (error)
          console.log(error)
        else
          console.log(messages?.value);
      })
  })
```

when I try I have this error message :

> Error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Anyone know where I make a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

For the above-mentioned permissions Admin grant is required for that permission to be accepted for that application:

[image]

It should be green tick marked when the permission is granted for this check in portal once:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that you can make the api call from Graph Explorer. Based on your error message, you won't be able to bypass the permission issue in the SPFx project.

Second, take a look at the permissions that were required from Graph Explorer. Match this permission in the project (package solution file).  You don't need more than what is provided in MS Graph Explorer.

If you can get the api call made form Graph API, you should be good to go.